# Fill a hole in a donut

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to make a donut and I created this hole - how can I fill it up?

[image]

Comment: Your connection will not be ideal unless the two "sides" have the same number of subdivisions (ie all the points on the "icing" have their own point to connect to on the donut.) Select all the faces on the bottom part of your mesh (large squares) and press right-click then select "subdivide. once that's done, you should be able to select the top and bottom "edges" of the "hole", right click and select "bridge edge loops".

Comment: Very helpful - thank you :)

Comment: Hey , no problem. The only issue this introduces though, is that I can see you're using a Subdivision Surface modifier, which generally benefits from fewer subdivisions, instead of more as we introduced here.  You might now find that some of the sides of your donut are more "blocky" than intended. A better solution perhaps , is to un-subdivide the icing, but that is a slightly more involved process, possibly involving "separating" the icing into its own object, using a Decimate Modifier Set to "Unsubdivide" (2 iterations), and then joining it back up again. It's up to you what looks best.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the polygons around the hole and press <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)